# Display multiple record on one line in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a query that will show all the selected records EXCEPT the MAX record (there can be up to 5 records per query). However, it displays it on separate rows. How do I display the result in one row?

Current data:

```
John Smith 
Jack Smith
Gerald Smith
```

Desired data in one row (or in separate fields but not multiple rows) :

John Smith; Jack Smith; Gerald Smith

SQL statement:

```
 SELECT distinct /*all existing records */
 rtrim(ltrim(pn.sFirstName + ' ' + pn.uLastName)) as record1,
 '' as record2,
 ''  as record3,
 '' as record4,
 '' as record5
 FROM tenant t (nolock)
 INNER JOIN person pn (nolock) on pn.hmy = t.person
 WHERE pn.hmy <>
 (SELECT MAX(pn.hmy) 
 FROM tenant t (nolock)
 INNER JOIN person pn (nolock) on pn.hmy = t.person
 WHERE t.scode = '111111'
 )and t.scode = '111111'
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: This looks like SQL Server (`nolock`, `ltrim(rtrim())`, and the use of `+` for string concatenation). . . could you tag it with the right database?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I did had a SQL tag. Plus, I have SQL in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using SQL Server.  If you are using version 2005 or later, then you can do this with `row_number()`:

```
SELECT (case when seqnum = 2 then rtrim(ltrim(max(pn.sFirstName+ ' ' + pn.uLastName)))  as record1,
       (case when seqnum = 3 then rtrim(ltrim(max(pn.sFirstName+ ' ' + pn.uLastName)))  as record2,
       (case when seqnum = 4 then rtrim(ltrim(max(pn.sFirstName+ ' ' + pn.uLastName)))  as record3,
       (case when seqnum = 5 then rtrim(ltrim(max(pn.sFirstName+ ' ' + pn.uLastName)))  as record4,
       (case when seqnum = 6 then rtrim(ltrim(max(pn.sFirstName+ ' ' + pn.uLastName)))  as record5
 FROM (select pn.*,
              ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t.scode order by pn.hmy desc) as seqnum
       from tenant t (nolock) INNER JOIN
            person pn (nolock)
            on pn.hmy = t.person
       where t.scode = '111111'
      ) pn
```

The inner query assigns a sequential number based on `pn.hmy`, with the biggest value being 1.  The outer query summarizes the data, using a conditional to choose the second through sixth values.

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable to hold that information, something like

```
declare @result;
set @result = '';

select @result = @result + ',' + rtrim(ltrim(pn.sFirstName + ' ' + pn.uLastName))  
from ..... 

select substring(@result, 0, len(@result));
```